# Change color of each bar in Likert package R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have this dataframe:

```
library(likert)
library(ggplot2)

DF<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5),B=c(2,3,4,5,1),C=c(3,1,2,4,5),D=c(2,3,4,5,1),E=c(1,2,4,3,5))
categories<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

I convert the observations to factors and I create a likert object using the `likert` package:

```
DF <- DF %>% 
  mutate(across(contains(categories), ~ ordered(., levels = c(1,2,3,4,5),labels = c(1,2,3,4,5))))

likert_data<-likert(DF)
```

Now I create the graph below using the `likert.plot` function from the same package:

```
plot(likert_data,plot.percent.neutral=F,center=3.5)
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to change the color of each bar according to the category (A,B,C,D,E), so to get something like this:

[image]

The legend doesn't have to be exactly like this. I know how to change the colors of the graph as a whole but don't know how to change the colors of single bars. Do you have any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Based on your comment, I added some more information at the end.

---

#### Original Answer

This uses the libraries `shades`, `ggplotify`, `grid`, `gtable`, and `gridExtra`.

I'm going to provide the code altogether first. After that, I've broken it down with explanations.

```
library(likert)
library(tidyverse)
library(shades)    # for colors
library(ggplotify) # change back to ggplot
library(gtable)    
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

x = plot(likert_data, plot.percent.neutral = F,
         center = 3.5, group = categories) 
x

xx <- plot(likert_data, plot.percent.neutral = F,
          center = 3.5, group = categories) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")         # <------ no legend

y <- ggplotGrob(xx)                         # make it a grid object
filling <- which(grepl("#5AB4AC", y$grobs)) # returned 6, 15

#------------- modify the plot -------------
for(each in y$grobs[[6]]$children) {        # find where fill used
  print(each)
  print(each$gp$fill)
}

# make color gradients for new color gradients
rainbow <- c(gradient(c("darkred", "mistyrose"), 3),
             gradient(c("#FF7F00", "lightgoldenrod"), 3),
             gradient(c("darkgreen", "lightgreen"), 3), 
             gradient(c("darkblue", "lightblue"), 3),
             gradient(c("purple4", "plum"), 3))

# light gray, dark gray
greys = c("gray74", "gray40")

# first pallet has those colors left of the 0 line
# get the light values out of the rainbow of colors
whL <- seq(3, length(rainbow), by = 3)
negs <- c(rev(rainbow[whL]), rep(greys, each = 5))
y$grobs[[6]]$children[[4]]$gp$fill <- negs     # add to the plot

# get the remaining colors out of the rainbow
rainGp <- c(seq(2, length(rainbow), by = 3), seq(1, length(rainbow), by = 3))
rainbow2 <- rainbow[rainGp] # select only those that apply
y$grobs[[6]]$children[[5]]$gp$fill <- rainbow2 # add to the plot

grid::grid.draw(y) # take a look using grid
(xx <- as.ggplot(y)) # or you can look as ggplot object (it's the same)

#------------- create the legend -------------
x2 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[1:3])), name = "")
redLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x2)), "guide-box")

x3 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[4:6])), name = "")
orgLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x3)), "guide-box")

x4 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[7:9])), name = "")
grnLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x4)), "guide-box")

x5 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[10:12])), name = "")
bluLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x5)), "guide-box")

x6 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[13:15])), name = "")
purLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x6)), "guide-box")

# get legends' object names
lgs <- grep("Leg", names(.GlobalEnv), value = T) 
# fix order         <------- order may be different you on your computer
lgs <- lgs[c(4, 3, 2, 5, 1)]
lgs <- lapply(lgs, get)          # capture objects instead of strings
legging <- do.call("rbind", lgs) # make this one gtable instead of 5

gb <- textGrob("Response", x = 1, y = .5, just = c("right", "center"))

arr <- arrangeGrob(grobs = list(gb, legging), widths = c(1, 2),
                   ncol = 2, nrow = 1, padding = 0)

#------------ the plot's ready --------------
# new plot object
grid.arrange(xx, arr, heights = c(7, 3), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
```

All that to get this:

[image]

I didn't change the code you provided other than to assign the Likert plot to an object.

I also created another version without the legend. Primarily you'll use the plot without the legend (except when making legends later).

```
x = plot(likert_data, plot.percent.neutral = F,
         center = 3.5, group = categories) 

xx <- plot(likert_data, plot.percent.neutral = F,
          center = 3.5, group = categories) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Using help, I found that the top default color for Likert plots is `#5AB4AC`, so I used that information to search the `ggplotGrob`.

```
y <- ggplotGrob(xx)
filling <- which(grepl("#5AB4AC", y$grobs)) # returned 6, 15
```

This returns that the 6th grob and 15th grob contain something assigned to this color. The first is the plot. The second is the legend.

---

---

#### Changing the Plot

Next, I looked further into the color assignment in the plot. I needed to see how the colors were broken down in the background.

```
for(each in y$grobs[[6]]$children) {
  print(each)
  print(each$gp$fill)
}
```

From the `for` call, I found that I needed to look at the 4th and 5th child within the 6th grob.

This is what was returned from the for statement (truncated to just show the 4th and 5th child).

```
# rect[geom_rect.rect.871] 
# [1] "#F2E5CB" "#F2E5CB" "#F2E5CB" "#F2E5CB" "#F2E5CB" "#E5CC98" "#E5CC98"
# [8] "#E5CC98" "#E5CC98" "#E5CC98" "#D8B365" "#D8B365" "#D8B365" "#D8B365"
# [15] "#D8B365"
# rect[geom_rect.rect.873] 
# [1] "#ACD9D5" "#ACD9D5" "#ACD9D5" "#ACD9D5" "#ACD9D5" "#5AB4AC" "#5AB4AC"
# [8] "#5AB4AC" "#5AB4AC" "#5AB4AC"
```

You can see that the color I mentioned is only in the 5th child. What you see here is that the 4th child has those values to the left of the vertical line for zero on the x-axis. The 5th child has the two highest responses; the two to the right of the vertical zero line.

Next, I created a palette to replace these colors.

```
rainbow <- c(gradient(c("darkred", "mistyrose"), 3),
             gradient(c("#FF7F00", "lightgoldenrod"), 3),
             gradient(c("darkgreen", "lightgreen"), 3), 
             gradient(c("darkblue", "lightblue"), 3),
             gradient(c("purple4", "plum"), 3))
```

I tried a few different methods to make this more dynamic, but the color intensity was really uneven, so I set it manually.

Next, the two grey colors.

```
# light gray, dark gray
greys = c("gray74", "gray40")
```

To reset the colors for the 4th child, I need the replacement colors for Likert responses of 1, 2, and 3. So I need to peel the light colors out of the `rainbow`.

```
whL <- seq(3, length(rainbow), by = 3)
negs <- c(rev(rainbow[whL]), rep(greys, each = 5))
y$grobs[[6]]$children[[4]]$gp$fill <- negs     # add to the plot
```

Now it's time to change the Likert responses for 4 and 5.

```
# get the remaining colors out of the rainbow
rainGp <- c(seq(2, length(rainbow), by = 3), seq(1, length(rainbow), by = 3))
rainbow2 <- rainbow[rainGp]                    # select only those that apply
y$grobs[[6]]$children[[5]]$gp$fill <- rainbow2 # add to the plot
```

At this point, your plot's colors have all changed.

```
grid::grid.draw(y) # take a look using grid
(xx <- as.ggplot(y)) # or you can look as ggplot object (it's the same)
```

[image]

---

---

#### Changing the Legend

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I used `ggplot` to make the legends for me. Essentially, I will plot the graph five times—once for each color group. Each time I plot it, I'll make everything one color group. (For example, the first one only uses shades of red.) After I create the plot, I use `gtable` to extract the legend.

```
x2 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[1:3])), name = "")
x2
redLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x2)), "guide-box")

x3 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[4:6])), name = "")
x3
orgLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x3)), "guide-box")

x4 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[7:9])), name = "")
x4
grnLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x4)), "guide-box")

x5 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[10:12])), name = "")
x5
bluLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x5)), "guide-box")

x6 <- x + scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(greys), rev(rainbow[13:15])), name = "")
x6
purLeg <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(x6)), "guide-box")
```

I could have just added each of these legends to a list, but I just called them to a list instead. Since it searches the environment, there's no telling what order you'll get these back in. I have fixed the order here, but it could be different on your device.

After collecting their names and putting them in order, I `get` them (change from strings to objects), then I bound them into one `gtable`.

```
# get legends' object names
lgs <- grep("Leg", names(.GlobalEnv), value = T) 

# fix order         <------- order may be different you on your computer
lgs <- lgs[c(4, 3, 2, 5, 1)]
lgs <- lapply(lgs, get)          # capture objects instead of strings
legging <- do.call("rbind", lgs) # make this one gtable instead of 5
```

You could actually see the legends at this point using `grid.draw()`.

Now that I've got the legends, I am going to add the legend label, "Response." (I took it off because it looked odd repeated for each string of colors.)

Next, put the consolidated legends and the label together into one object.

```
# legend title
gb <- textGrob("Response", x = 1, y = .5, just = c("right", "center"))
# consolidate legend title and legends
arr <- arrangeGrob(grobs = list(gb, legging), widths = c(1, 2),
                   ncol = 2, nrow = 1, padding = 0)
```

Next, combine the color-changed plot and the color-changed legend. (You're done!)

```
# new plot object
grid.arrange(xx, arr, heights = c(6, 4), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
```

You may have to adjust the `heights` here. It's not relative, so depending on how you're using it, you may need to adjust.

[image]

#### Information Based on your Comments

I created a few functions that do most of the plot color-changing work with several constraints.

I haven't tested this nearly enough to say how well it will work regardless of the data.

This assumes you'll use the argument `center = 3.5` and use a 1-5 Likert scale. If you were not aware, for the Likert library, you have to have the same number of levels in every question to plot. (Keep the empty levels.)

```
library(likert)
library(tidyverse)
library(shades)    # for colors
library(ggplotify) # change back to ggplot
library(gtable)    
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

x = plot(likert_data, plot.percent.neutral = F,
         center = 3.5, group = categories) 
xx <- plot(likert_data, plot.percent.neutral = F,
           center = 3.5, group = categories) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")         # <------ no legend

y <- ggplotGrob(xx)                         # make it a grid object
filling <- which(grepl("#5AB4AC", y$grobs)) # returned 6 (ran without legend)

#-------------- modify the plot ----------------
# this assumes that you have used the parameter center = 3.5 in Likert plot
# this works for 1-5 Likert questions (rows in the plot)
# assumes only 5 levels of Likert
# assumes there is at least 1 neg & 1 pos in each row!

defaultNeg = c("1" = "#D8B365", "2" = "#E5CC98", "3" = "#F2E5CB")
defaultPos = c("4" = "#ACD9D5", "5" = "#5AB4AC")

# make color gradients for new color gradients
grays = c("gray74", "gray40")     # light gray, dark gray
rainbow <- c(gradient(c("darkred", "mistyrose"), 3),
             gradient(c("#FF7F00", "lightgoldenrod"), 3),
             gradient(c("darkgreen", "lightgreen"), 3), 
             gradient(c("darkblue", "lightblue"), 3),
             gradient(c("purple4", "plum"), 3))

# this function is called with collector()
getY <- function(grob_sub, w, freq) {
  # grob_sub, w: (wGrob) index of affected child; 
  #    freq: number to filter for
  wh <- table(grob_sub[[w]]$y %>% as.numeric()) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
    filter(Freq < freq) %>% select(id) %>% unlist()
  return(wh)
}

# this function is called within replaceFill()
collector <- function(grob_sub, what) { # what: either defaultNeg or defaultPos
  idsL <- seq(length(rainbow), 3, by = -3) # set up for light & dark color extract
  idsD <- c(seq(2, length(rainbow), by = 3), seq(1, length(rainbow), by = 3))
  i = 0
  for(each in grob_sub) {        # find where fill used in children
    i = i + 1
    if(is.null(each$gp$fill)) {next} # not it
    else {
      fills = each$gp$fill
      if(length(fills) < 2) {next}   # not it
      if(any(fills %in% what)) {
        wGrob = i       # if contains the colors
        break           # no reason to keep looking
      }
    }
  }
  wCol <- grob_sub[[wGrob]]$gp$fill       # get colors
# if there is a missing level
  if(isTRUE(any(length(wCol)/5 != 10 & any(length(wCol)/5 != 15)))) {
    # rule out the grey values (if they're missing no special handling needed)
    tb <- table(wCol) %>% as.data.frame()
    if(nrow(tb %>% filter(wCol == defaultNeg[3], Freq == 5)) > 0) {
      break # move on, the item missing is a gray entry
    } 
    if(nrow(tb %>% filter(wCol == defaultNeg[3], Freq < 5)) > 0) {
      wh <- getY(grob_sub, wGrob, 3) # if light colors, there's 3 in each row
      idsL <- idsL[-wh]
      wCol[wCol == defaultNeg[3]] <- rainbow[idsL]
    } 
    if(nrow(tb %>% filter(wCol %in% defaultPos, Freq < 5)) > 0) {
      ins <- outs <- FALSE    # is it an inner or outer color (or both)?
      if(tb[1, "Freq"] < 5) {outs <- TRUE}
      if(tb[2, "Freq"] < 5) {ins <- TRUE}
      wh <- getY(grob_sub, wGrob, 2) # regardless of path are there three in each row?
      if(isTRUE(all(ins, outs))) { # this is not handled at this time  
        message("Handling not added for multiple positive missing levels.")
      } else if(isTRUE(ins)) {
        idsD <- idsD[-wh]
        wCol[wCol == defaultPos[1] | wCol == defaultPos[2]] <- rainbow[idsD]
      } else if(isTRUE(outs)) {
        idsD <- idsD[-wh]
        wCol[wCol == defaultPos[1] | wCol == defaultPos[2]] <- rainbow[idsD]
      }
    }
  }
  else {                         # there are no missing levels starts here
    if(defaultNeg[3] %in% wCol){ # if this one element is in the vector
      wCol[wCol == defaultNeg[3]] <- rainbow[idsL] # change light colors
    } else if(any(defaultPos %in% wCol)) {
      wCol[wCol == defaultPos[1] | wCol == defaultPos[2]] <- rainbow[idsD]
    }
  } # regardless if something is missing, gray values are the same
  if(any(wCol %in% defaultNeg[1:2])) {
    wCol <- gsub(defaultNeg[1], grays[2], wCol)
    wCol <- gsub(defaultNeg[2], grays[1], wCol)
  }
  return(list(wCol, wGrob))      # return colors and child indices
}

# grob_sub at plot level here this is  y$grobs[[6]]$children
replaceFill <- function(grob_sub) { 
  negs <- collector(grob_sub, defaultNeg) # call for positives
  poss <- collector(grob_sub, defaultPos) # call for negatives
  return(list(negs, poss))
}

#--------------- make the legend & combine the plot -------------
makeLegends <- function(xx, x, rainbow) { 
  # xx is the plot with the fixed colors and no legend
  # x is a plot with a legend
  # rainbow 15 color array/vector will all of the non-gray colors
  # ---
  # create sequences for each part of the rainbow
  cols <- c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple")
  i = 1
  lgs = list()
  for(each in cols) {
    newX <- x + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c(rev(grays), rev(rainbow[i:(i + 2)])), name = "")
    lgs[[each]] <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(newX)), "guide-box")
    i = i + 3
  }
  legging <- do.call("rbind", lgs) # combine legends into one legend
  # create legend title grob
  tg <- textGrob("Response", x = 1, y = .5, just = c("right", "center"))
  # assemble legends with legend title
  arr <- arrangeGrob(grobs = list(tg, legging), widths = c(1, 2),
                     ncol = 2, nrow = 1, padding = 0)
  result <- grid.arrange(xx, arr, heights = c(7, 3), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
  result
}
```

To use the functions, this is what you need to do. I've added a modified data frame to show what happens when there are empty levels.

```
DF <- rbind(DF, DF) %>% mutate(B = ifelse(B == 3, 4, B),
                               C = ifelse(C == 4, 5, C)) %>%
  mutate(across(contains(categories),
                ~ordered(., levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                         labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))))

# call the function to get the colors and ids
np <- replaceFill(y$grobs[[6]]$children)

# change the colors with the ids
y$grobs[[6]]$children[[np[[1]][[2]]]]$gp$fill <- np[[1]][[1]]
y$grobs[[6]]$children[[np[[2]][[2]]]]$gp$fill <- np[[2]][[1]]

#------------------------------ plot color finished 
grid::grid.draw(y)   # take a look using grid
(xx <- as.ggplot(y)) # or you can look as ggplot object (it's the same)

#------------ see the finished plot  --------------
plt <- makeLegends(xx, x, rainbow) # create the finished plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(plt)
```

The modded data using these functions produces this plot.

[image]

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thanks a lot for your time! Only one question, if I want to use this code on a dataframe with a different number of columns (for example, 3 columns instead of 5), where should I modify the script? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what happens if one bar does not have an occurence for a color? For example, if nobody in A answered 3?

Comment: I added to my answer. It should work a bit easier for different data. BTW, I didn't spend a ton of time testing it or working out the inefficiencies, so you may run into some odd problems. When in doubt, send yourself a message.  (From within any of the functions you can use the command `message` to print function objects.)